# How Jersey works on Tomcat Server?

Tags: tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

As per the Apache tomcat description at http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html, tomcat doesn't support JAX-RS  webservices.

But Jersey, which is JAX-RS reference implementation works fine in tomcat.

I am trying to understand how Jersey jar makes JAX RS work on tomcat? 
Or does tomcat actually support JAX-RS application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"doesn't support"* is a bit ambiguous I guess. You interpreted as *"doesn't support at all"*, when really it means *"doesn't have a JAX-RS implementation out the box"*.

All JAX-RS implementations run as a servlet (or some can be run as a servlet filter), so all an implementation needs is a servlet container to run, which vanilla Tomcat is.

Comment: Thanks! But if JAX-RS implementations run as a servlet, what difference does **TomEE JAXRS** support to say additional JAX-RS support compared to **Tomcat**?

Comment: TomEE comes with a JAX-RS implemenation, CXF